# Change font/background colour when using screen?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, prompt

I've been getting used to the screen command in Linux and it's my new favourite command.

I'm modifying my screenrc file to make screen more powerful.

One thing I'd like to do would be to have different font colours between screen instances. I think it would make it easy to keep track of which screen I'm on.

I haven't found any examples or seen anything helpful in the documentation for what I want.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You say that you want this *to keep track of which screen*. In this case, wouldn't it make more sense to use different colours in **every** screen of each screen instances, instead of using differnt colours just for different invocations of `screen`, as you requested?

Answer (score 4):

You can edit your `.bashrc` to look at the value of `$TERM`:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ screen -S demo
$ echo $TERM
screen.xterm-256color
```

If your `TERM` setting includes the string `screen`, you may be somewhat same to presume you're in a `screen` session.  You can then adjust your `PS1` (Prompt String 1) accordingly to set color or other indicators on your prompt as you like:

```
if [[ $TERM =~ screen ]]; then
    export PS1='\[\e[1;33;44m\]\w \$\[\e[0m\] '
fi
```

Those numbers and encoded escape characters are ANSI control sequences which set foreground and background color settings.  <kbd>ESC</kbd>`[` is the sequence to start altering terminal settings, `1` means 'bold', `33` means 'yellow foreground', `44` means 'blue background', and `m` means 'we're done making changes now, and those numbers were for color settings'.  Similarly, in the later sequence, `0` means 'back to default' which is typically non-bold white on black.

There are many tools like [this one](http://ezprompt.net/) to help you make as colorful and as snazzed-up a prompt as you might wish to have.

Comment: This would set the same colour in all instances of *screen*.